# keyup is not working in mobile browser , Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-handling, keyup

```html
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search"
      @keyup.enter="startSearching"
      v-model="searchInput"
      class="search-box-input"
      :disabled="!isActive"
    />
```

I am expecting to trigger `startSearching()` function in mobile browser

Comment: It should work. It might be a browser or OS issue. Can you please test your keyboard events here ? https://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html

Comment: Does the `@keyup` event get triggered? Check the code sent, maybe not the same as on desktop.